# Undefined field error while field exists in the schema - Solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am using Solr in cloud mode. A couple of days ago the cloud went down and after restart I am having trouble. Whenever I query from my custom search engine Solr outputs following error.

> INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/elevate params{q=++++حفج&df=content_urdu&hl=true&hl.simple.post=&indent=true&start=0&hl.fragsize=190&fq=group:web&fq=(title_urdu:[''+TO+*]+AND+url:[''+TO+*]+AND+content_urdu:[''+TO+*])&hl.fl=content_urdu&rows=10&wt=json&hl.simple.pre=} status=400 QTime=1
>
> ERROR org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field: "title_urdu"

However my `schema.xml` has that field in it and i can see it in my Solr dashboard as well.

I am not sure what's going on here. Please guide me.

Comment: It would helpful if you could share the schema.xml

Comment: Can you find the schema as it should be defined in the zookeeper store?